# C# dump analysis: newbie question: where's the rest of my callstack?

Tags: c#, debugging, callstack, debug-symbols

I have quite some experience in debugging memory dumps, so now that I have a C# problem, I try to solve this using memory dump analysis too, but this seems not to work:

When I use my user-interactive application, I get a `System.ArgumentNullException`: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name`.

When I see this in my Visual Studio environment, or when I debug the memory dump I've taken at that moment, these are the first lines of the call stack:

```
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, 
      Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   ...
```

However, when I click `Copy Details`, I see quite a lot more, as you can see:

```
   at Application.Client.Desktop.Controls.UserAuthentication.OnUserLogOn(User user)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, 
      Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, 
      Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   ...
```

So, the problem is somewhere in the `OnUserLogon()` function, who is working with the `user` input variable, and I can only imagine how interesting the knowledge of this variable might be :-)

But as my call stack does not go that deep, I don't have access to that variable.

One thing which might be important: while trying to debug, I see "Symbol loading skipped", and I can confirm that I have two symbol sources:

- Microsoft Symbol Servers
- Some company-owned website

In order to see a full C# call stack, do I need to add more symbol sources or is there any other thing I should do?

For your information, when debugging the memory dump, I have already tried `Debug with Managed Only` and `Debug with Mixed`, none of those possibilities solved my issue.

Thanks in advance

**Edit after first comment**
Apparently there might be some unexpectedly interesting information in the call stack, so hereby I show the entire call stack as shown in Visual Studio `Call Stack` window:

```
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object obj)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    MyApplication.Desktop.exe!MyApplication.Client.Desktop.App.Main()   Unknown
```

Does this give any more information? (Like the thread where the actual problem happens? Please be aware that quite some information has been optimised away and I can't re-compile the application: I'm only allowed to work on a DLL, being used by that application)

**Edit2: added more information**
While doing the test a new time, I have seen following call stack in a so-called `Worker Thread`:

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Diagnostics.StackFrameHelper.InitializeSourceInfo(int iSkip, bool fNeedFileInfo, System.Exception exception) Line 109   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.CaptureStackTrace(int iSkip, bool fNeedFileInfo, System.Threading.Thread targetThread, System.Exception e) Line 523  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.StackTrace(System.Exception e, bool fNeedFileInfo) Line 407  C#
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Environment.GetStackTrace(System.Exception e, bool needFileInfo) Line 1264  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Exception.GetStackTrace(bool needFileInfo) Line 354 C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Exception.ToString(bool needFileLineInfo, bool needMessage) Line 450    C#
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.ExceptionLayoutRenderer.AppendToString(System.Text.StringBuilder sb, System.Exception ex) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.ExceptionLayoutRenderer.AppendException(System.Exception currentException, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<NLog.Config.ExceptionRenderingFormat> renderFormats, System.Text.StringBuilder builder) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.ExceptionLayoutRenderer.Append(System.Text.StringBuilder builder, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer.RenderAppendBuilder(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder builder) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout.RenderAllRenderers(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder target) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Layouts.Layout.RenderAllocateBuilder(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder reusableBuilder)   Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Layouts.Layout.Render(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers.OnExceptionLayoutRendererWrapper.RenderInner(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers.WrapperLayoutRendererBase.Append(System.Text.StringBuilder builder, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)  Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer.RenderAppendBuilder(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder builder) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout.RenderAllRenderers(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder target) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Layouts.Layout.RenderAppendBuilder(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder target, bool cacheLayoutResult)  Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Targets.FileTarget.RenderFormattedMessageToStream(NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Text.StringBuilder formatBuilder, char[] transformBuffer, System.IO.MemoryStream streamTarget)   Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Targets.FileTarget.Write(System.Collections.Generic.IList<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents)   Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(System.Collections.Generic.IList<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents)    Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvents(System.Collections.Generic.IList<NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents) Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.WriteEventsInQueue(int batchSize, string reason)  Unknown
    NLog.dll!NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.ProcessPendingEvents(object state)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 980  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 928  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() Line 713   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() Line 670   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() Line 425  C#
```

Unfortunately almost every object is optimised away, so I can't give more information.

Comment: From this `System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall` I suspect the actual error occurs in some other thread. So you may need to switch to that thread.